# Unable to retrieve collection data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to mongodb in this way. I got the code from w3schools, but although it connects to the `localhost:3000` port, it does not return an error.

**app.js**

```js
const express = require("express"); 
const app = express(); 
const PORT = 3000; 
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = "mongodb+srv://**r*t:***@cluster0.e6a3vn3.mongodb.net/***?retryWrites=true&w=majority"; var conn = MongoClient.connect(url); // returns a Promise


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("***");
        dbo.collection("blogs").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
          db.close();
        });
      }); })

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Başarılı"); 
});
```

The mongodb connection url in the url variable works correctly. For example, when I create a db.js page, when I create schema and redirect the schema table there to this page, the code works. For example:

**db.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const blogSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    age: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
   
 }, 
);

const Blog=mongoose.model('Blog',blogSchema)

module.exports=Blog
```

**app.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Blog = require("./models/db");


const db = "mongodb+srv://**:***@cluster0.e6a3vn3.mongodb.net/***?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(db).then((result) => console.log("Connected")).catch((err) => console.log(err));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Blog.find().then((result) => {
        res.json( result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
```

Can't we access the table directly like in mysql?

I watched a lot of videos and read a lot of documents, but I couldn't figure out how to connect directly to the database without using schema.

Comment: In your first example you are using `MongoClient` which is the native MongoDB driver for Node. In the second example you are using `mongoose` which is an Object Modelling package built on top of the  native `MongoClient`. It would be advisable to pick one or the other and stick with it. If you need to connect directly to MongoDB then you can use client tools such as the [mongosh shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) or [Compass GUI](https://www.mongodb.com/products/tools/compass).